# Can a text box in a UserForm contain formula?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have had a look online for an answer to this but no joy with coming across one as of yet. Is it possible to have a text box in a UserForm be dynamic?

My current idea is to have 3 columns of text boxes, in Column 1 & 2 the user need to enter there data and was wondering if in Column 3 there is a way to show the value involving Column 1 and Column 2?

If this isn't possible, are you able to reference a cell on a sheet and then get the useform to display the cells value?

Ideally i would like this to be possible as it provides the user with a quick check to ensure they've entered the data right.

**Edit 1**

`TextBox18.Value = (TextBox1.Value + TextBox10.Value) / 2`
I found that this line of code allowed me to reference two text boxes dynamically but textbox 18 concatenating rather than added the numbers. Is there a way round this?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, a textbox cannot contain a formula as such. But you can either do the calculations in the worksheet and display the values in the textbox or use `Application.WorksheetFunction` like `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(1,1,1)` to display the calculated value in textbox. But it depends on the complexity of your calculation.

Comment: @Arul `TextBox18.Value = (TextBox1.Value + TextBox10.Value) / 2` i have found that this line of code will allow me to concatenating the two values rather than add them. Do you know a way round this?

Comment: You could use the `TextBox1_Change()`, `TextBox2_Change()` etc. event to dynamically update the value of textbox 18. Will that do?

Comment: @LocEngineer If i use this code, which i think it what you meant by your comment, `TextBox46_Change() = (TextBox1_Change() + TextBox36_Change()) / 2` I get a compiler error whenever i try and use that txt box. Is that because ive misinterpreted what you meant? or not?

Comment: @LocEngineer I still get a compiler error, using your code above.

Comment: WHAT error do you get? Please give us enough info to actually help you.

Comment: haha thats fine, do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively something like this could help, this will add the values and not concatenate them:

```
TextBox3.Value = (Val(TextBox1.Value) + Val(TextBox2.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the TextBox_Change() event method to dynamically update values.

Example:

```
Sub TextBox46_Change()
  TextBox46.Value=(TextBox1.Value + TextBox36.Value) / 2
End Sub
```